# Python - Fails when checking for a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I am trying to perform a check to see if a folder exists, if yes then I want to have one file downloaded else have another file downloaded. Given below is the code:

```
    base = os.path.join(current_directory, 'files', customer, str(end_date))
    if os.path.isdir(base):
        sales = pd.read_csv(base + f'/final_output/{customer}_{end_date}.csv',sep=',')
    else:
        sales = pd.read_csv(base + f'/filenotsent.txt', sep='\t')
```

I see even though the folder I am checking is a directory, it still performs the else condition. Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Are you checkinf for a `directory` or a `file`?

Comment: @user5173426,  I am just checking if a directory exists

Comment: why not using `os.path.join` when creating the csv file names?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, there is no error. Just that instead of performing the if statement it executes the else part of the condition..

Comment: then your directory doesn't exist. Period. Python works. Your script does not.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, unfortunately the folder exists. That is why I am wondering why it skips the if statement..

Comment: is that absolute/relative? how are you setting it? with raw prefixes? please show the actual value of `current_directory` and print `base` and post output here.

Answer (score -1):

with `os.path.isdir` you are checking if base is a directory (aka not a file).

what you want is `os.path.exists` which check if this directory exist.

Comment: seems that it"s checking for a directory, see read_csv commands afterwards.